# How to import js file in react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, import

```
$( "#left_arrow" ).click(function() {   
  if ($(".left_block").hasClass("w-0")) {
     $(".left_block" ).removeClass("w-0");        
   }else{
     $(".left_block" ).addClass("w-0");
   }
 });
```

In the custom.js I am having the script code above feature is not working when importing with below.

```
 import * as script from '../js/custom.js';
```

In the Html page when I load this file its working but when writing in react component its not working

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't even need jQuery for handling click events and adding classes, you should have React do that.

Comment: but its not working

Comment: I second Andrew Li, you need to move on from jQuery, and figure this out in React. If you refactor this question, and ask how you could implement something like this in React, you be much better off.

Comment: how this feature need to be implemented

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix with jquery with React, What you want to achieve can easily be implemented in React like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    class: 'w-0'
  }
  handleClick=()=> {
    if(this.state.class === 'w-0') {
      this.setState({class: ''})
    } else{
      this.setState({class: 'w-0'})
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div id="left_arrow" className="left_arrow" onClick={this.handleClick}><i className="fa fa-chevron-left" />Arrow</div>
          
          <div className={"left_block " + this.state.class}>Hello World</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: <div id="left_arrow" className="left_arrow"><i className="fa fa-chevron-left" /></div> 
 <div id="right_arrow" className="right_arrow"><i className="fa fa-chevron-right" /></div>

Comment: in the return i am having these two divs one for right and one for left.

Comment: You need to have an onClick on whichever div you want to click as mentioned in the above snippet

Comment: <div id="left_arrow" className="left_arrow" onClick={this.handleClick}><i className="fa fa-chevron-left" /></div> 
where i need to place this.state

Comment: Where do you want to add this class. Can you add your React code

Comment: I am new to react just now learning you may feel it easy sorry for that can you elobarate

Comment: <div id="left_arrow" className="left_arrow"><i className="fa fa-chevron-left" /></div>

Comment: <div className={"left_block " + this.state.class}>Hello World</div>
whats the need and where to implement handle click already inserted

Comment: Its all in the snippet, where and how you want to implement, In your jquery example you were having a block with class `left-block` so for my snippet example I took it as a div with text `Hello World` , `className={"left_block " + this.state.class}` adds or removed the class after `left_block`

Comment: with the code you provided its working but the left block is not showing at all
when i click on left arrow it should hide again if i click again left block should appears

Comment: <div className={"left_block " + this.state.class}
In this we need to set properly class we are setting w-o so entire thing will be removed i need this to be done on click events

Comment: its working.. but on render the left block is removed and again on click on that the left block should be displayed but it is not showing